# Scroll down a bit then up after Ajax request due to reached scroll position

Tags: jquery, ajax, scroll, user-experience

Im loading some results with ajax on button click. After each click i scroll to the postion with

```
    success: function(data) {                       

        $("#test").html(data).fadeIn("slow"); 
        
        $('html , body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: ($(scrolltarget).offset().top -90)
        }, 600);
        
        return false;                       
        
    },
```

The problem, after the first load the position is reached so it does not scroll after another click. After each request i want to scroll down a bit and up so the user sees that something happened like the first time. Im not in favor of using a loading gif.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the jquery scroll to method as described here:

[Scroll to an element with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/scroll-to-an-element-with-jquery)